# OpenCart suddenly stopped working: HTTP Error 500

Tags: http, opencart

I use OpenCart v1.5.5.1 for the last month and a couple dozen orders came through fine.

Suddenly today, I get a HTTP Error 500, when accessing www.domain.com/shop/*, but www.domain.com works fine. So far, I tried to no avail:

- rebooted the server
- cleaned out /logs/error.txt
- removed .htaccess

**The last error in the logs were:**

```
2013-03-17 19:10:11 - PHP Notice:  Error: Table 'shop_db.geo' doesn't exist<br />Error No: 1146<br />SELECT g.id,g.full_name,g.name,g.postcode,z.zone_id,z.country_id FROM geo g LEFT JOIN zone z ON g.zone_id = z.zone_id WHERE g.name LIKE '99%' AND g.postcode <> '' ORDER BY population DESC LIMIT 12 in /var/www/domain.com/html/shop/system/database/mysql.php on line 50
2013-03-17 19:10:11 - PHP Notice:  Error: Table 'shop_db.geo' doesn't exist<br />Error No: 1146<br />SELECT g.id,g.full_name,g.name,g.postcode,z.zone_id,z.country_id FROM geo g LEFT JOIN zone z ON g.zone_id = z.zone_id WHERE g.name LIKE '990%' AND g.postcode <> '' ORDER BY population DESC LIMIT 12 in /var/www/domain.com/html/shop/system/database/mysql.php on line 50
```

**Here is the .htaccess**

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

    # 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
    # php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

    # 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
    # php_value post_max_size 999M

    # 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
    # php_value max_execution_time 200

    # 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
    # php_value max_input_time 200

    # 7. disable open_basedir limitations
    # php_admin_value open_basedir none

    # 8. force the administration log-in screen to always load in HTTPS
    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    #RewriteRule (.*) https://www.overair.ca/shop/admin/ [R]
```

**and php.ini**

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
register_globals = Off;
default_charset = UTF-8;
memory_limit = 64M;
max_execution_time = 36000;
upload_max_filesize = 999M;
safe_mode = Off;
mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
session.use_cookies = On;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 172800;
allow_url_fopen = on;
;display_errors = 1;
;error_reporting = E_ALL;
```

However, I noticed that they've been around for the last few days with no issues. Before I restore from a backup and lose a couple orders, I was hoping someone could help.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Make sure your `error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL` (I notice the line is commented out in the ini you show), if the server is returning 500 it should be logging errors telling you why, the error message you show are certainly not the root cause of the problem

Comment: @DaveRandom thank you. I set that and looked at the log under /shop/system/logs/error.txt but nothing is logged, is there another log location?

Comment: I'm making some fairly serious assumptions about the way your server is set up here but it is quite a common setup: it's likely in that case that this is an Apache error and not an error with any of your/the opencart code, and that the logs are being created in some kind of administrative area, quite possibly one your host does not provide access to. You should contact you host and ask them to tell you where any other log locations may be and ask them to inspect the global error logs.

Comment: @DaveRandom I'll try to look at the server errors. We are on a dedicated cloud server.

Comment: If you have access to it you need to look at httpd.conf and see where the proper error logs are being directed (try and grep for the [`ErrorLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#errorlog) directive). The path you gave their and the format of the log file you show seems to suggest that you are not looking at the proper error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Error no. 1146 means the table it is trying to connect, is not in the database, you might want to check the database and see the table is there and also check the config.php. I hope you might find out whats the problem!!!